# How to make a model create a view not table?

Tags: sails.js

I have the following model

```
module.exports={
  tableName: 'agentLoad',
    migrate: 'safe',
  attributes: {
  id:  {  type: 'int'},
  load: {type:'int'}
}

};
```

I want to make this model a view not a table .. anyone knows how?

Comment: I am quite new to Sails, but as far as I know, views are handled in a controller. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I meant the Database view not the MVC view 
as in Create view x as selec * from y
Thnx anyways

Comment: Is there any reason you need to be so? As far as I know, the waterline ORM should abstract the data behind your models. Perhaps in the waterline documentation you could get some hints: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs

Comment: Use this generator https://github.com/juliandavidmr/sails-inverse-model it will create MVC code for you. You can then use `view` and `index` for single item and tabular views respectively.